# How do I access embedded Mongodb document through Jade and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, pug

I can obtain a non embedded field from my document through jade by doing:

```
each user, i in gauss_buff
   tr
   td #{user.build_num} // where build_num is an element in my document.
```

However, how should one access an embedded document via Jade. Doing
user.embedded_doc_name.field
didn't work.

I used `#{user.not_embedded_field}` and I receive:

```
{
  "not_embedded_field" : not_embedded_field_value,
  "embedded_document": [{
         "embedded_field1" : some_value
         "embedded_field2" : some_other_value
```

I have hunted around, but can't find how to do this anywhere. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Then use it like an array: `#{user.embedded_document[0].embedded_field1}`